# why i have error in name notebook in hyperas?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, hyperas

I am doing an efficient way to build neural network architectures and I am basing it on this work:
https://towardsdatascience.com/a-guide-to-an-efficient-way-to-build-neural-network-architectures-part-i-hyper-parameter-8129009f131b
https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas/blob/master/README.md#notebook-adjustment

but i have a problem with the finally part.
when in the code ask me for  notebook_name='simple_notebook'.
i tried change name of folder or python file but dont work
please help me

```
X_train, Y_train, X_val, Y_val = data()
best_run, best_model = optim.minimize(model=model,
                                      data=data,
                                      algo=tpe.suggest,
                                      max_evals=5,
                                      trials=Trials(),
                                      notebook_name='simple_notebook')
```

Comment: Could you show or describe the error you are getting?

Comment: SyntaxError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    [... skipping hidden 1 frame]

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1956/292979561.py in <module>
      6                                       trials=Trials(),
----> 7                                       notebook_name='simple_notebook')    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 1184: invalid continuation byte

Comment: make sure that this is the name of your file as indicated in the [documentation](https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas/blob/master/README.md#notebook-adjustment)